# How to implement an easy secure socket connection

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, tls1.2

I'm writing a simple client-server game in c#. my prototype works well with socket programming. i used `socket` class with `SocketAsyncEventArgs` for asyncing my code. now for alpha version i like (must) create a secure connection. but i don't have any background about security and SSL and TLS.

I found a class for this purpose: `sslstream`. but .Net docs are not understandable for me as a beginner. another problem is `SocketAsyncEventArgs` doesn't work by streams like `TCPClient` Class.

so can anyone guide me how to implement a simple secure connection with sockets? there is two requirements: 

1- it should be fast an low-latency and I appreciate it supports non blocking (async) pattern.

2- it should support very small messages. my game commands are 10 bytes average. I don't like encrypted commands become 128 bytes!

because my server is not public and only my clients connect to it, i don't like to register and buy a certificate.

please provide a step-by-step answer. first how to create some keys (Public- private... i don't know) second how to authenticate client and third how to communicate securely.

sincerely Thanks for reading this question until end and previously thanks for your answers. best regards!

Comment: "please provide a step-by-step answer." - um, that sounds a lot like "please do this very lengthy, very complex, very nuanced thing for me, from start to end"; TLS is complex, ultimately; socket IO is complex; RPC is complex; there is no *brief answer* for this other than "use a library that already does this" (noting that the library will be *large*; this is *not* a small topic). gRPC or WCF might be options, for example.

Comment: thanks for your replay Marc. do you mean that a class like `sslstream` is not enough for my project? and also i appreciate tutorials, articles or even books if it help me. to be honest i don't know from where i must start!

Comment: `SslStream` is just one part of what is involved here; *yes* you will probabaly need `SslStream` *as part of it*, but that doesn't give you everything that you need; you're going to need to deal with framing, back-buffers, etc and if you want async you need to deal with topic like the threading model; "pipelines" (System.IO.Pipelines) is a good way of solving most of those problems, but "pipelines" doesn't work directly with Stream - so then you need a pipelines/Stream bridge; these things exist, but that's where the library part comes in!

Comment: AFAIK SocketAsyncEventArgs and SSLStream do not work together: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881238/c-ssl-with-socketasynceventargs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those how are not familiar with cryptography like me, there is a very good start point for creating a secure scheme in the Microsoft docs.
[.NET Framework Cryptography Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cryptography-model)

> Creating a cryptographic scheme is not a trivial task! ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/creating-a-cryptographic-scheme))

but this tutorial is basic material about implementing a basic security system.

**EDIT:** Microsoft have deleted the page about creating a cryptographic scheme, so i paste a google chached version for you:

> Creating a Cryptographic Scheme
>
> The cryptographic components of the .NET Framework can be combined to
> create different schemes to encrypt and decrypt data.
>
> A simple cryptographic scheme for encrypting and decrypting data might
> specify the following steps:
>
> - Each party generates a public/private key pair.
> - The parties exchange their public keys.
> - Each party generates a secret key for TripleDES encryption, for example, and encrypts the newly created key using the other's public key.
> - Each party sends the data to the other and combines the other's secret key with its own, in a particular order, to create a new secret key.
> - The parties then initiate a conversation using symmetric encryption.
>
> Creating a cryptographic scheme is not a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend:
https://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/using-secure-sockets-in-.net.html

(*) Using a self-signed certificate is highly not recommended. DO NOT use a self-signed certificate in production.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can you please tell me why "Using a self-signed certificate is highly not recommended"? considering my project is not in public use and only my game clients (and also attackers) attempt to connect to my server.

Comment: One reason is that It exposes your clients to a "man in the middle" attack. When you use a CA, there is a reliable authority that tells your clients that you are indeed Mokhabadi. When you use a self-signed ceritifcate you tell your clients: "Just trust me, I am who I say I am."...